# this.state.data.map is not a function continues to show even though I have an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm receiving an object and pushing to an array. I can see the array in my console.log but still it refuses to map out the li's.

What am I doing wrong?

```
state = {
    startDate: null,
    endDate: null,
    data: []
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data =>
            this.setState({ data: this.state.data.push(data) }),
            console.log(this.state.data)
        )
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
            {this.state.data.map(item => (
                <li key={item.id}>{item.id} - {item.title}</li>
            )}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Console.log:

```
[]
0: {userId: 1, id: 1, title: "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit", body: "quia et suscipit↵suscipit recusandae consequuntur …strum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"}
length: 1
```

Comment: Calling `.push` on an array does *not* return the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value of [Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is

> The new **length** property of the object upon which the method was called.

so, you're basically overwriting `data` in your state by the length of the array instead of the array itself,

update your state using `data => this.setState(prevState => ({ data: [...prevState.data, data] }))`

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    startDate: null,
    endDate: null,
    data: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(
        data => this.setState(prevState => ({ data: [...prevState.data, data] }))
      );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>        
          {this.state.data.map(item => {
            return (
              <li key={item.id}>
                {item.id} - {item.title}
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```